# Javascript issue with moving list items up and down

Tags: javascript, events

Recently started learning javascript, and am at the moment trying to build a simple app, that is an ul, with list items, where each li has two buttons, to move that li up or down.

But, I'm running into problem. Last item in list can never be moved up

```js
    var ul = document.querySelector('ul');
    
    ul.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
     let clicked = e.target;
     let li  = clicked.parentNode;
     let next    = li.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling;    
      let prev    = li.previousElementSibling;
        
        if (clicked.className === 'down') {
         ul.removeChild(li);
            ul.insertBefore(li, next);
        } else if (clicked.className === 'up') {
         ul.removeChild(li);
         ul.insertBefore(li, prev);
        }
    });
```

```html
    <ul>
        <li>item1 <button class="down">Move down</button><button class="up">Move up</button></li>
        <li>item2 <button class="down">Move down</button><button class="up">Move up</button></li>
        <li>item3 <button class="down">Move down</button><button class="up">Move up</button></li>
        <li>item4 <button class="down">Move down</button><button class="up">Move up</button></li>
        <li>item5 <button class="down">Move down</button><button class="up">Move up</button></li>
    </ul>
```

Here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hu13x8w0/3/

Can someone explain to me, why it wont work in those 2 cases? What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the browser's console (F12 to open Dev Tools in most browsers) you'll see an error like this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nextElementSibling' of null
```

That's because on this line:

```
li.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling;
```

...the last element's `.nextSibling` is `null` (it doesn't have a next sibling). You need to test for `null` rather than just chaining an extra `.nextElementSibling` on the end:

```js
    var ul = document.querySelector('ul');
    
    ul.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
     let clicked = e.target;
     let li  = clicked.parentNode;
     let next    = li.nextElementSibling;               // <-- Code changed
        if (next != null) next = next.nextElementSibling;  // <-- Code inserted
      let prev    = li.previousElementSibling;
        
        if (clicked.className === 'down') {
         ul.insertBefore(li, next);
        } else if (clicked.className === 'up') {
         ul.insertBefore(li, prev);
        }
    });
```

```html
    <ul>
        <li>item1 <button class="down">Move down</button><button class="up">Move up</button></li>
        <li>item2 <button class="down">Move down</button><button class="up">Move up</button></li>
        <li>item3 <button class="down">Move down</button><button class="up">Move up</button></li>
        <li>item4 <button class="down">Move down</button><button class="up">Move up</button></li>
        <li>item5 <button class="down">Move down</button><button class="up">Move up</button></li>
    </ul>
```

Note that you don't need the calls to `.removeChild()`, because `.insertBefore()` will *move* the element (not copy it).

Comment: Note that this causes `Move Up` on the top row to wrap around.

Comment: @Paulpro - That happened with the OP's original code too. I wasn't sure if that was on purpose.

Comment: Also, there is nothing wrong with your answer, but I had some random recommendations for the OP that could be added to it if you want. 1) The calls to `removeChild` can be removed, as they have no effect since they are always followed by `insertBefore` which moves the `li` node from wherever it was in the DOM. 2) `const` makes more sense than `let` for all those variables (and to use as a default whenever possible), `let` implies that they might be modified later.

Comment: @Paulpro - Actually I was just editing to remove the `.removeChild()` lines with a note about that. I agree about `const` versus `let`, but that's getting more into general style so I think your comment is enough rather than putting it in the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answers guys. Quick follow up question: why const? Values for clicked, li next and prev are being set whenever any of the buttons are clicked. If I use const instead of let, wont those values always stay the same?

Comment: Each time the function is called it gets a fresh set of local variables, the variables aren't retained between calls. In the code in my answer, the `next` variable may get reassigned in the `if` statement so it can't be a `const`, but the other variables could be.